# Disabling camera in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

All

I want to disable the camera  option in device. I start services to get the camera option and then i will lock using lock() method. How can i get camera object to access it?

thanks
Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it from a device administrator, but the user has to explicitly enable it and it is only available on ICS. Here's the reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Disable camera -    Specifies that the camera should be disabled. Note that this doesn't have to be a permanent disabling. The camera can be enabled/disabled dynamically based on context, time, and so on. Introduced in Android 4.0.

read this :- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

for getting camera object If you have opened it within your own application, you must hold onto that Camera object (e.g., in your activity). You cannot get it back.

I suppose if u acquired  a lock on camera, you need to release it, use unLock().

Normally, the camera is locked to the process with an active Camera object until release() is called. To allow rapid handoff between processes, you can call this method to release the camera temporarily for another process to use; once the other process is done you can call reconnect() to reclaim the camera.

Comment: I tried device admin apis, it will support only above 4.0, I want to do it from 2.2 android. so only i trying to get camera obj

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need first control the camera like a super user in your phone, you can do this wit the [DeviceAdministration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) class, this allows some hardware and super user controls like the camera, you can check this [repo](https://github.com/barneyElDinosaurio/LockCamera) like example.